# How come input is not in header?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a Minimal viable product, I am not to sure why my text input is not inside the header logo as my text input is already inside the header div. Could someone please help me out? As you can see the input is sitting below the div, I want it to be next to the amazon logo.

Here is the link to the sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-cdn-yfoh0?file=/src/Header.js

Header.js

```
export default function Header() {
  return (
    <div className='header'>

      <img className='header__logo'
       src='http://pngimg.com/uploads/amazon/amazon_PNG11.png'
      />

      <div className='header__search' >
        <input 
        className='heade__search'
        type='text'
        />
      </div>

    
    </div>
  )
}
```

Header.css

```
.header {
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: "flex";
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #131921;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

.header__logo {
  width: 100px;
  /* Keep aspect ratio */
  object-fit: contain;
  margin: 0 20px;
  margin-top: 18px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: should be display: flex, not "flex"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be display: flex, not display: "flex". Remove the quotation marks.

Font: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container